# play .flv stream video from rtmp URL in android

Tags: wowza, streaming-flv-video

I am working on upstream and downstream. I upstream video on wowza server. Problem that i am getting is video saved on server with .flv extension is not getting played. To play video URL is:

```
rtmp://WowzaserverIPAddress:1935/live/test.flv
```

I searched on how to play .flv file in android. But it is not played. Please help me out how to either save video on wowza server with .mp4 or how to play .flv stream video from rtmp url.

I tried to change the above url with following

```
rtmp://10.8.23.79:1935/live/test.mp4
```

But it does not create file.

Please help me out. I am not asking for code but please give some ideas to sort it out.

Thanks in advance

Guys help me out please. suggest me something..

Answer (score 0):

If the file is on your Wowza server it can be used by following these steps:

1. Make sure server is set up to play VOD: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?35-How-to-play-a-video-on-demand-file)
2. Copy the file into the Wowza server's content directory, [install-dir]/content.
3. It should work then with the url rtmp://wowza-ipadress:1935/vod/flv:test.flv

Good Luck.

Comment: thank for answering. Actually i have to play file on mobile. I am successfully able to play video file with .flv on wowza server. But problem is how to play .flv on android device. There are two options either i can save file on wowza server with .mp4 or how to play .flv file on android. i searched how to play .flv file what i found is flv file must be saved in SD card before with .html file and will run in webview. But i have to livestream video. I dont want to save video on mobile.

Comment: I see.  To play on Android 4.x, you'll need to re-encode your video to an mp4 file, as you mention, and then enable HLS in Wowza and play it that way.  For Gingerbread devices, you can play that rtmp url provided a flash player is installed on the device (and that must be side-loaded AFAIK, as the Adobe player is no longer in the Play Store).

Comment: We need to re-encode .flv vedio file to an .mp4 file. Is is not possible to save .mp4 vedio on wowza server. How we will  convert .flv to .mp4

Comment: You can use a number of different tools to do that, including ffmpeg. A google search will give you more ideas including free and paid tools.  I am not sure you mean by "save .mp4 vidio on wowza server".  You will put the .mp4 file in the content directory as you did the .flv file.

Comment: Yes your are right the way m saving .flv file on server. i want to save .mp4 file on wowoza server. So its easy to play.